# For multilingual sites, do I set up a separate taxonomy?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

If I decide to set up an additional language for my site, do I need to manually set up a translated version of my existing taxonomy, or is there a module that can manage that process for me (not the translating part, obviously)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [I18N](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) project gives you multiple ways to deal with multi-language taxonomies:

- Assign a vocabulary a language, making it specific for that language only
- Translate Terms into different languages
- Assign each term a language, so that you can have different terms based on the chosen language, but still a common vocabulary.

Comment: Excellent! I understood from looking at it previously that it could present different language versions of a node, but didn't know that it could also deal with terms, too. That's good news.